# Table for tasks

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have two applications: web site and windows service. Web site saves tasks in db, windows service pull tasks from db, process and save it with information about result or error. 
I need help to design schema...

What is the best way? Create one table Tasks with status column (new, completed, error) and index or two tables (TaskQueue and CompletedTasks)? Something else?

P.S.: Task table have 5-7 columns (nvarchar or int) necessary for task processing in addition to ID and Status columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd go with one table and a status column (we use this pattern for batch processing of transactions from some of our web sites).  That will also make reporting a lot easier, and let you query things that may be stuck in a transitory status, etc.

(An addendum)

Depending on the lifespan of your tasks, and if you intend to scale these out, you may want to consider a message queueing system down the road, or potentially some custom status history tables to log your tasks as they transition steps - but those suggestions may be a bit too heavyweight for the project you're working.